# 「MonacaアプリでFaceBook認証を使ったログイン実装」の削除された回答

Tags: 討議

https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/35922/5793

> こちらのhttps://npmjs.com/package/aerogear-cordova-oauth2ですが、monacaで実装できた方いらっしゃいますか？cordovaでは実装可能かもしれませんが、当方のmonaca環境ではエラーが発生しビルドできません。
>   他のcordova-plugin-facebook4などもmonacaのandroidsdkバージョンが対応していないためできず、monacaでFacebook公式アプリ経由でのログインができるプラグインは現状無いかと思われます。

今は見えませんが「これは回答ではない」という趣旨のコメントがついていました。

しかし、実質的な内容は

・他の回答の間違いの指摘
・元の質問に対する回答

です。削除すべきではないと思います。

Comment: 確か自分も削除に投票した気がするのですが、なるほど、確かにご指摘の通りです。すいません。削除取り消しに賛成します。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[別質問にも同様の回答が投稿されていた](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/35425/facebook%E8%AA%8D%E8%A8%BC%E3%81%AE%E9%9A%9B%E3%81%AB-%E5%85%AC%E5%BC%8F%E3%82%A2%E3%83%97%E3%83%AA%E3%82%92%E4%BB%8B%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E8%AA%8D%E8%A8%BC%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84/35921#35921)のですが、そちらの質問・既存回答と比べたときに、ご指摘の質問は「Facebookアプリの認証情報を使って」という点が明示されないように感じ、回答もFacebookアプリを考慮しないものになっています。コメントでのやり取りに対する指摘ではありますが、回答になっているかと言われると...ちょっと迷うところです。コメントに変換するとよいかもしれないとは思いました。

一方回答単体で見ると、「monacaで実装できた方いらっしゃいますか？」という記述から、投稿者が回答を求めているように感じたので、回答ではなく質問にした方がよいだろうと考えたような記憶があります。そこで「FaceBook認証の際に、公式アプリを介して認証したい」の質問の方にそのようなコメントを残し、「MonacaアプリでFaceBook認証を使ったログイン実装」の方は削除したのだったと思います。

いずれにせよ、レビューを待たずして削除するほどではなかったのは確かなので、当該投稿は削除を取り消し、コメントも修正しておきました。